# How can ı find a similarity value of a data to specific group of data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a data set. Some information of customers is kept in this data set and its columns are contains numbers.

These data contain information about the behavior of the customers a month before leaving the system. So there is exact information that these customers will leave the system within a month.
An up-to-date customer behavior data set is also available. But since these are up to date, we do not know whether they will leave the system or not.

Both data set contains same features.

In fact, I would like to find a probability value of leaving the system for each customer in the second data set with using what I learned from the first data set. How similar to the customers in this first data set.

I tried many methods for this, but they were not healthy. Because I cannot create a data set that customers who will not leave the system. For this reason, the algorithms in the classic sklearn library (classifier or regression algorithms) couldn't solved my problem in real life because I can't determine the Y column content precisely.

I am not sure if this question can be asked here.

But what method should I follow for such a problem? Is there an algorithm that can solve this? What kind of research should I do? With which keywords can I analyze the solution of the problem?

Comment: I think an example of each dataset could be really helpful. but ill assume both datasets have the same features. I might suggest finding the most important features that points-out the user will leave the system. (can be done by random_forest for example) afterward, try and find the similarities between "up-to-date" customers and features from before. you can also use feature engineering to add "probablity_of_leaving" and use regression algorithms to predict it.

Comment: @itaybenhaim thanks for reply, both data set contains same features. Actually finding the similarity is my main problem.

Comment: Just wondering, with no particular expertise, if most current customers do not leave the system, could a model be developed where the current customers are used as "don't leave the system" examples?  Over time, the model could be refined with actual "leave the system" results.  There would be an initial bias to "stay in the system", but perhaps it's a starting point.

Comment: [Learning Classifiers from Only Positive and Unlabeled Data](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/posonly.pdf) shows a possible technique.  The paper also references other techniques.